# Is there an equivalent of Javascript's `resolve` function (from the Promise constructor) in Dart?

Tags: javascript, dart, asynchronous, dom, promise

I want to create a function that returns a future. A value will be resolved at a specific time. However, the value will have to be resolved from inside a callback. In Javascript, I could do something like this:

```js
function delay(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000);
  });
}
```

I don't see any clear solution for this in Dart, could anyone show me a way to do this (or a way around this)?
If you need any clarification, feel free to ask a comment.

Edit: to be more clear, I'll provide context and source code I've created.

I am trying to make a function (method, really) that returns after a single event happening to an element. I first wrote it in Javascript -

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.on = function(eventName) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var handler = function(event) {
            resolve(null);
            this.removeEventListener(eventName, handler);
        };
        this.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
    });
};
```

and you can use it like this: `await myButton.on("click"); alert("Button clicked first time");`.

I'm trying to recreate it in Dart + HTML for the sake of toying around, and here's the code so far.

```dart
import "dart:html";

extension on HtmlElement {
  on(String name) {
    void handler(Event event) {
      removeEventListener(name, handler);
      // Do something to actually return from the method...
    }

    addEventListener(name, handler);
  }
}

void main() {}
```

Edit: for the curious, the complete code can be found  [here](https://gist.github.com/gosoccerboy5/ac4c51f4f045564528e1076fd01f536d) or [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211006152312/https://gist.github.com/gosoccerboy5/ac4c51f4f045564528e1076fd01f536d).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not familiar with JavaScript `Promise`s, but presuming that you want `await myButton.on("click")` to complete only after the `handler` function has executed at least once, you can use a [`Completer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Completer-class.html):

```dart
import "dart:async";
import "dart:html";

extension on HtmlElement {
  Future<void> on(String name) {
    final completer = Completer<void>();

    void handler(Event event) {
      removeEventListener(name, handler);
      completer.complete();
    }

    addEventListener(name, handler);
    return completer.future;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Promise can be resolved a maximum of *one* time, so it probably makes sense to automatically remove the event listener after the first click. And instead of modifying the `HtmlElement.prototype` which is an unhygienic practice, write a simple `onclick` function that accepts an HtmlElement as input -

```js
function onclick(elem) {
  return new Promise(r =>
    elem.addEventListener("click", r, {once: true})
  )
}

function main () {
  onclick(document.forms.myapp.mybutton)
    .then(event => console.log(event.target))
    
  onclick(document.forms.myapp.otherbutton)
    .then(event => console.log(event.target))
}

main()
```

```html
<form id="myapp">
  <button type="button" name="mybutton">A</button>
  <button type="button" name="otherbutton">B</button>
</form>
```